# Launch camera from HTML 5 app running on Windows 8?

Tags: html, windows-8, camera

I've seen examples using XAML and writing some code in C# - is it possible just using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is a blog showing how to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2012/09/05/tutorial-series-using-winjs-amp-winrt-to-build-a-fun-html5-camera-application.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can write following method for launch camera

```
 function capturePhoto() {
   var capture = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();

    capture.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo)


        .then(function (file) {
            if (file) {
                return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
            }
        });
```